# How to make elements appear under a <UL> in Firefox & IE8?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I recently applied the answer supplied for the question "[How can I get a `<ul>` to be evenly spaced across the content area it exists in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504776/how-can-i-get-a-ul-to-be-evenly-spaced-across-the-content-area-it-exists-in/3505133#3505133)", to my list of tabs.

This worked fine for me, but any elements after the list of tabs appeared to the right of the `<ul/>` element, instead of under it. I applied a `clear: both;` rule to the CSS for my `<ul/>` and that solved the problem in FireFox. Now elements were appearing under the list, as I expected... except it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8.

This is the CSS for the `<ul/>`:

```
#SearchForm ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    clear: both; 
}
```

However, if I change the width rule to `width: 101%;`, this makes everything appear correctly in IE8 and Firefox. Why wouldn't this work in IE8? Setting something to 101% width seems a bit hacky. Is there a better way for me to ensure that all elements appear under the `<ul/>` in all browsers?

Comment: Sounds like this question should go on [Doctype](http://doctype.com/) instead of here?

Comment: I think you might want to try applying the `clear: both` property to the element under the `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yi Jiang suggested, applying `clear: both` to the element after your `#SearchForm ul` will fix the problem:

```
<div id="SearchForm">
</div>
<div id="someOtherElement" style="clear: both">
</div>
```

The reason it doesn't work as expected when you apply clear to `#SearchForm ul` is because this only tells the `<ul>` to clear floats, not the elements after the `<ul>`.   Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/zzAmF/1/) showing it in action.